# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS usb 3.0 stops working during transfer and broken until restart

Tags: 20.04, usb

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04 last night. I have 6 USB 3.0 ports and 6 USB 2.0 ports. No issues with the USB 3.0 ports during several hours of use last night but I didn't do any data transfer.

Today trying to copy files from a flash drive I get an input output error, notice the drive is unmounted and none of my USB 3.0 ports are working (including my usb mouse and keyboard). I transfer everything to USB 2.0 ports and they work fine.

I restart and retry the file transfer and get the same issue after copying maybe 8-10GB worth  of files. The USB 3.0 ports are completely dead. Tried a 3rd restart and copying some of the files in smaller chunks which works for a few smaller transfers but after the 4th transfer the ports disconnect again and stop working.

Here is my lsusb on boot:

```
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0e8f:00a8 GreenAsia Inc. 2.4G RX
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 009 Device 002: ID 174c:3074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 SuperSpeed hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 174c:2074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 High-Speed hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

My lsusb with usb drive connected:

```
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0e8f:00a8 GreenAsia Inc. 2.4G RX
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 009 Device 002: ID 174c:3074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 SuperSpeed hub
Bus 009 Device 003: ID 0951:1666 Kingston Technology DataTraveler 100 G3/G4/SE9 G2
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 174c:2074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 High-Speed hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

My lsusb after the USB 3.0 ports stop working:

```
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 0e8f:00a8 GreenAsia Inc. 2.4G RX
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Does anyone have any idea what I can do to fix this? Thanks.

Update (not entirely sure how much of this is pertinent but I think this covers the time from the last successful transfer, to device failure and then moving the usb drive to a usb 2.0 port)

/var/log/syslog:

```
Jan 20 11:22:05 dunnetahl-desktop systemd[933]: Starting Tracker metadata extractor...
Jan 20 11:22:05 dunnetahl-desktop tracker-extract[3340]: Set scheduler policy to SCHED_IDLE
Jan 20 11:22:05 dunnetahl-desktop tracker-extract[3340]: Setting priority nice level to 19
Jan 20 11:22:05 dunnetahl-desktop dbus-daemon[956]: [session uid=1000 pid=956] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.Tracker1.Miner.Extract'
Jan 20 11:22:05 dunnetahl-desktop systemd[933]: Started Tracker metadata extractor.
Jan 20 11:22:05 dunnetahl-desktop tracker-extract[3340]: Warning: using insecure memory!
Jan 20 11:22:16 dunnetahl-desktop systemd[933]: tracker-extract.service: Succeeded.
Jan 20 11:22:36 dunnetahl-desktop tracker-store[3331]: OK
Jan 20 11:22:36 dunnetahl-desktop systemd[933]: tracker-store.service: Succeeded.
Jan 20 11:22:38 dunnetahl-desktop kernel: [  575.944723] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: xHCI host not responding to stop endpoint command.
Jan 20 11:22:38 dunnetahl-desktop kernel: [  575.944728] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: USBSTS:
Jan 20 11:22:38 dunnetahl-desktop kernel: [  575.944958] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: xHCI host controller not responding, assume dead
Jan 20 11:22:38 dunnetahl-desktop kernel: [  575.944976] xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: HC died; cleaning up
Jan 20 11:22:38 dunnetahl-desktop kernel: [  575.945019] usb 8-4: USB disconnect, device number 2
Jan 20 11:22:38 dunnetahl-desktop kernel: [  575.945063] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_TIME_OUT driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=35s
Jan 20 11:22:38 dunnetahl-desktop kernel: [  575.945070] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 01 f0 e9 a8 00 04 00 00
Jan 20 11:22:38 dunnetahl-desktop kernel: [  575.945076] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 32565672 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 9 prio class 0
Jan 20 11:22:38 dunnetahl-desktop kernel: [  575.945187] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_ERROR driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
Jan 20 11:22:38 dunnetahl-desktop kernel: [  575.945194] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 01 f0 ed a8 00 08 00 00
Jan 20 11:22:38 dunnetahl-desktop kernel: [  575.945200] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 32566696 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80700 phys_seg 17 prio class 0
Jan 20 11:22:38 dunnetahl-desktop kernel: [  575.945807] usb 9-2: USB disconnect, device number 3
Jan 20 11:22:38 dunnetahl-desktop kernel: [  575.960788] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdc, sector 32565672 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Jan 20 11:22:39 dunnetahl-desktop kernel: [  576.905657] usb 9-4: USB disconnect, device number 2
Jan 20 11:22:39 dunnetahl-desktop udisksd[713]: Cleaning up mount point /media/dunnetahl/32gigger (device 8:34 no longer exists)
Jan 20 11:22:39 dunnetahl-desktop dbus-daemon[956]: [session uid=1000 pid=956] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.Tracker1' unit='tracker-store.service' requested by ':1.3' (uid=1000 pid=941 comm="/usr/libexec/tracker-miner-fs " label="unconfined")
Jan 20 11:22:39 dunnetahl-desktop systemd[1]: media-dunnetahl-32gigger.mount: Succeeded.
Jan 20 11:22:39 dunnetahl-desktop dbus-daemon[956]: [session uid=1000 pid=956] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.Tracker1'
Jan 20 11:22:39 dunnetahl-desktop systemd[933]: media-dunnetahl-32gigger.mount: Succeeded.
Jan 20 11:22:39 dunnetahl-desktop systemd[1]: Stopping Clean the /media/dunnetahl/32gigger mount point...
Jan 20 11:22:39 dunnetahl-desktop systemd[933]: Starting Tracker metadata database store and lookup manager...
Jan 20 11:22:39 dunnetahl-desktop systemd[933]: Started Tracker metadata database store and lookup manager.
Jan 20 11:22:39 dunnetahl-desktop systemd[1]: clean-mount-point@media-dunnetahl-32gigger.service: Succeeded.
Jan 20 11:22:39 dunnetahl-desktop systemd[1]: Stopped Clean the /media/dunnetahl/32gigger mount point.
Jan 20 11:23:09 dunnetahl-desktop tracker-store[3399]: OK
```

Comment: Is there anything in your `/var/log/syslog` file involving the USB failure? If so, can you update your question to include the pertinent snippets? 

Comment: updated to include /var/log/syslog also formatted the drive to ntfs (from exfat), sucessfully copied 31gb to the drive and tried to copy from the drive back to another folder on main hdd and had the same issue with similar errors appearing in syslog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the warning of insecure memory usage as a clue and experimenting with reformatting the drive and several other drives I have come to the conclusion that there is some sort of physical problem with usb drive I was using. I have successfully done a bunch of other data transfers with other drives without issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem with an ASMedia device.

```
Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Linux idallen-oak 5.13.0-27-generic #29~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 14 00:32:30 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have a StarTech SDOCK4U33 4-slot USB 3 hard drive dock using ASMedia Technology:

```
Bus 004 Device 007: ID 174c:55aa ASMedia Technology Inc. Name: ASM1051E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1053E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1153 SATA 3Gb/s bridge, ASM1153E SATA 6Gb/s bridge
Bus 004 Device 008: ID 174c:55aa ASMedia Technology Inc. Name: ASM1051E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1053E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1153 SATA 3Gb/s bridge, ASM1153E SATA 6Gb/s bridge
Bus 004 Device 009: ID 174c:55aa ASMedia Technology Inc. Name: ASM1051E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1053E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1153 SATA 3Gb/s bridge, ASM1153E SATA 6Gb/s bridge
Bus 004 Device 010: ID 174c:55aa ASMedia Technology Inc. Name: ASM1051E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1053E SATA 6Gb/s bridge, ASM1153 SATA 3Gb/s bridge, ASM1153E SATA 6Gb/s bridge
```

If I reboot my Linux machine, the dock causes these USB errors during the boot:

```
Jan 18 21:56:52 idallen-oak kernel: [   13.254357] usb 4-3: device descriptor read/8, error -110
Jan 18 21:57:03 idallen-oak kernel: [   24.398290] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Abort failed to stop command ring: -110
Jan 18 21:57:03 idallen-oak kernel: [   24.400554] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI host controller not responding, assume dead
Jan 18 21:57:03 idallen-oak kernel: [   24.402820] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: HC died; cleaning up
```

Losing that controller at boot means many of my other USB devices are
not detected.

If I unplug the hard drive dock USB cable, the machine boots fine.  If I
then plug in the dock USB cable after the machine is up and running,
the above error happens (and I again lose many other USB devices).
Surely plugging in a USB device should not cause the whole controller
to fail and lose all the other working USB devices?

If I power off all of the drives in the hard drive dock and then
power them on, that seems to reset the dock and then everything works
fine again when I reboot.  The dock is correctly detected at boot and
everything works.  If I then reboot with the dock running, the problem
returns until I power cycle the dock and reboot again.

There is something about this dock that xhci_hcd doesn't like when the
dock is left powered on across a reboot.

More details (syslog, etc.) upon request.